# XIRR function in libre office Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I did a calculation for finding XIRR using libre office `XIRR` function.
My Beginning Market Value on `31-Dec-2010` is `100,000`. I deposited `500,000` on `01-Feb-2011` and withdrawn `5000` from `01-May-2011`. My Ending Market value on `01-Jun-2011` is `594353.42`.

```
Column A     Column B
-100000       31/12/10
 500000       01/02/11
-5000         01/05/11
 594353.42    01/06/11
```

My XIRR formula is `=XIRR(A1:A4,B1:B4)`. After using this formula, the result is `96826862.1762233`. Its very strange even I am loosing money here. What I did wrong with them?

Comment: You invest 10000 and get 50000 out a month later. Then you invest 5000 and get 594353 a month later. That is a very high earning.

Comment: No. I deposited 500000 out a month later. and withdrawn 5000

Comment: So, you are telling me I should use negative for inflow and positive for outflow right?

Comment: Yes. xirr is calculating on  cash flows, not balances. How much is added and withdrawn.